# error in storing unique values in 2d vector in r

Tags: r

```
        > uc<-unique(r1$COMPANY)
        > uc
         [1] AZTEC                      CALIBER POINT              COGNIZANT                  CYBAGE                     CYBAGE                     DLF                       
         [7] GODREJ AND BOYCE LTD.      HCL TECHNOLOGIES           I-FLEX                     INFOCEPTS                  INFOSYS                    JATAAYU SOFTWARE (P) LTD. 
        [13] KANBAY                     KPIT                       L & T  LTD.                L & T INFOTECH             MASTEK                     mBlazon SOLUTION PVT. LTD.
        [19] MOTOR INDUSTRIES LTD       NOVATECH                   PATNI COMPUTER SOFTWARE    RF ARRAYS                  S.M. WIRELESS PVT. LTD.    SATYAM COMPUTERS          
        [25] SATYAM COMPUTERS           SATYAM COMPUTERS LTD.      SHOBHA DEVELOPERS          SOHAM's FOUNDTION ENGG.    SYNTEL LTD.                TCS                       
        [31] TECH MAHINDRA LTD.         ULTRA TECH CEMENT          VRITTI SOLUTIONS           ABO SOFTWARE               ARTEFACT PROJECTS LTD.     EATON                     
        [37] FORCE MOTORS               H.C.C.                     HEXAWARE TECHNOLOGIES      HJB GROUP COMPANY, OMAN    IBM DAKSH                  INDIAN MILITARY ACADEMY   
        [43] INDO RAMA SYNTHETICS       INFOSPECTRUM PVT. LTD.     JYOTI STRUCTUIRES LTD.     KALPATARU                  KONE ELEVATORS             L & T ( e- SOLUTIONS)     
        [49] LAMBENT                    MAHINDRA & MAHINDRA LTD.   MAYTAS INFRA PVT. LTD.     MOTOR INDUSTRIES LTD .     ORIENT CEMENT              PERSISTENT SYSTEMS PVT.LTD
        [55] PREMIERE TECHNMOLOGY       SCHNEIDER                  SETH CONSTRUCTION          SIEMENS                    SIMPLEX                    SMS PARYAWARAN            
        [61] SOFT LINK INTERNATIONAL    VARROC ENGINEERING, PUNE  

> f<-length(uc)
> tt<-mat.or.vec(length(uc),3)
> for(n in 1:f)
+ {
+ tt[n,1]=uc[n]
+ tt[n,2]=5
+ tt[n,3]=9
+ }
> tt
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    3    5    9
 [2,]    4    5    9
 [3,]    5    5    9
 [4,]    6    5    9
 [5,]    7    5    9
 [6,]    8    5    9
 [7,]   11    5    9
 [8,]   13    5    9
 [9,]   16    5    9
[10,]   20    5    9
[11,]   22    5    9
[12,]   23    5    9
[13,]   26    5    9
[14,]   28    5    9
[15,]   29    5    9
[16,]   31    5    9
[17,]   34    5    9
[18,]   36    5    9
[19,]   37    5    9
[20,]   39    5    9
[21,]   41    5    9
[22,]   44    5    9
[23,]   45    5    9
[24,]   46    5    9
[25,]   47    5    9
[26,]   48    5    9
[27,]   51    5    9
[28,]   56    5    9
[29,]   57    5    9
[30,]   58    5    9
[31,]   59    5    9
[32,]   60    5    9
[33,]   62    5    9
[34,]    1    5    9
[35,]    2    5    9
[36,]    9    5    9
[37,]   10    5    9
[38,]   12    5    9
[39,]   14    5    9
[40,]   15    5    9
[41,]   17    5    9
[42,]   18    5    9
[43,]   19    5    9
[44,]   21    5    9
[45,]   24    5    9
[46,]   25    5    9
[47,]   27    5    9
[48,]   30    5    9
[49,]   32    5    9
[50,]   33    5    9
[51,]   35    5    9
[52,]   38    5    9
[53,]   40    5    9
[54,]   42    5    9
[55,]   43    5    9
[56,]   49    5    9
[57,]   50    5    9
[58,]   52    5    9
[59,]   53    5    9
[60,]   54    5    9
[61,]   55    5    9
[62,]   61    5    9

> strsplit(r1$COMPANY," ")
Error in strsplit(r1$COMPANY, " ") : non-character argument
```

I want t[n,1] to store all unique values of r1$COMPANY present in vector uc but it shows some random numbers.Please help to resolve the error.Also I would like to know how to obtain just first word from r1$COMPANY. I tried to split it on space character but it shows error.

Comment: Your error makes me think that `COMPANY` is not a character which means you can't split the string. Have you tried `as.character`?

Comment: COMPANY is a column which I have obtained by reading csv file

Comment: In `read.csv()`, use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and try your code here again.

Comment: stringsAsFactors=FALSE tried this but problem still exist

Comment: Try `uc <- with(r1, as.character(unique(COMPANY)))`

Comment: @Alex thank you uc <- with(r1, as.character(unique(COMPANY))) this worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jason and @Metrics mentioned, it appears that `uc` is a factor rather than a character. To remedy this, define `uc` as follows:

```
uc <- with(r1, as.character(unique(COMPANY)))
```

The key here is `as.character()`, which will convert a factor variable to a character variable. Any string manipulation functions should now work on `uc`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# I think `uc` is factor in your case (check using str(uc)). If it is character, it will give the solution as expected. Consider the following example:  
uc<-names(mtcars)
#str(uc)
#chr [1:11] "mpg" "cyl" "disp" "hp" "drat" "wt" "qsec" "vs" "am" "gear" "carb"
f<-length(uc)
 tt<-mat.or.vec(f,3)
for(n in 1:f) {
       tt[n,1]<-uc[n]
     tt[n,2]<-5
      tt[n,3]<-9
     }

> tt

tt
      [,1]   [,2] [,3]
 [1,] "mpg"  "5"  "9" 
 [2,] "cyl"  "5"  "9" 
 [3,] "disp" "5"  "9" 
 [4,] "hp"   "5"  "9" 
 [5,] "drat" "5"  "9" 
 [6,] "wt"   "5"  "9" 
 [7,] "qsec" "5"  "9" 
 [8,] "vs"   "5"  "9" 
 [9,] "am"   "5"  "9" 
[10,] "gear" "5"  "9" 
[11,] "carb" "5"  "9"
```